# Can't authorise Google script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm pretty sure Google changed something recently, because my script for archiving certain emails older than 30 days has stopped working.

It requires "authorisation".  Usually I open the script, choose "doGet" from the function drop down and press "run" and then I'm allowed to authorise it.  But this time it brings up a window saying I need to submit my app for verification.

Looks like they think it's a public facing app, but it's just operating on my own email account. How can I allow it to run?

Here is the link to my script;
https://script.google.com/d/1knE0Bpsrk2lTQ5SsoiebLNfbouY9uHtBWL5SZIiHmr4cHn-fK1upeJUQ/edit

Comment: Does the new authorization window have the 'show advanced' option? If you click on it, there might be the link at the very bottom saying 'Go to (your_app_name)(unsafe)'.

Comment: Ah thanks @AntonDementiev, that was it. I had expanded that earlier but didn't interpret that link as progressing forward, I had interpreted it to mean it would open the project for me to "authorise" it and send me in a circle (very tired of those).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Anton Dementiev's comment on my question was the answer.  If I click "Show advanced", there's a link saying "Go to [app name] (unsafe)" and then I can authorise it there.